# PDF to JPG; should i save to disk or create on-the-fly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, imageresizer

I see that in imageresizer docs; it is recommended to produce on the fly images rather than keeping images on the disk (for different sizes, etc.)

I wonder if this recommendation and best practice is still valid for showing PDF page thumbnails and JPGs.
I have a flipbook in my web application which shows a PDFs' pages.
Those pages are pre-rendered JPGs.
Is it better for me to save PDF pages as JPGs in a folder and show them in flipbook?
 Or 
is it better if i generate PDF jpgs on the fly using imageresizer.pdfium plugin each time a user navigates to flipbook page?

If not both, what is your recommendation and best usage scenario for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At minimum, cache the output to disk!

Some PDFs are fast to render; others are slow. You likely need to measure the performance and determine if the cache-miss latency is acceptable.

If not, you'll need to either pre-generate and track the images in all the sizes you need, or populate the disk cache before users access it.

Comment: Yes. Some JPGs take up to 30 seconds to be generated from PDF. I need to use ImageResizer URL api as a method in a separate thread job to generate JPG from PDF. Do you think it is a good way accomplish such a task?

Comment: There's no need to use the URL API over the .NET API for this, that just exhausts the request thread pool. I would suggest you use a queue-and-worker architecture for background processing, where the queue is persistent (perhaps in the database)? and transactional. Avoid unnecessary threads; they're expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for .NET API of IR before and couldn't find it. Now i searched again and found "Managed API" in docs.